# Ping is only succeeding one way

Tags: networking, arp

I have two devices (a PC and a laptop) on a small network connected by Ethernet. I have assigned static IP to the NIC of each device. The laptop's NIC has IP `192.168.1.101` and logical interface `enp0s31f6` and the PC's NIC has IP `192.168.1.103` and logical interface `enp1s0f2`.

From the PC, when I try to ping the laptop, it works fine:

```
$ ping -I enp1s0f2 192.168.1.101
PING 192.168.1.101 (192.168.1.101) from 192.168.1.103 enp1s0f2: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.354 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.377 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.260 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.418 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.253 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.101: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.250 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.101 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5123ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.250/0.318/0.418/0.067 ms
```

However, pinging from the laptop to the PC doesn't receive any icmp replies. On the PC, I am seeing the requests but no replies:

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp1s0f2 
[sudo] password for user: 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp1s0f2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:22:38.442345 IP 192.168.1.101 > user: ICMP echo request, id 62, seq 19, length 64
20:22:39.465977 IP 192.168.1.101 > user: ICMP echo request, id 62, seq 20, length 64
20:22:40.490038 IP 192.168.1.101 > user: ICMP echo request, id 62, seq 21, length 64
20:22:41.518012 IP 192.168.1.101 > user: ICMP echo request, id 62, seq 22, length 64
```

Looking at the ARP cache:

```
$ arp -a
? (192.168.1.101) at 48:9e:bd:75:b7:16 [ether] on enp1s0f2
? (192.168.1.101) at <incomplete> on enp1s0f3
```

I tried deleting the cache and retrying. When I successfully ping from PC to laptop, the first entry appears. When I fail to ping from laptop to PC, the second one appears.

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: How many Ethernet interfaces do you have on the PC, in `ip -br -4 addr`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your ARP cache, that little explanation after it, and the fact that it seems like you have to be specifying the source interface in your pings from the PC, it looks like it's trying to reply out a different interface (enp1s0f3).

My guess is there is an overlap with enp1s0f2 & enp1s0f3 having IP addresses in the same network.

Do these on the PC and show the output:

```
ifconfig
ip route list
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a firewall on the PC? Usually return traffic from outbound will work while inbound unsolicited traffic would be blocked.

Comment: No, there isn't a firewall. Or at least, I don't think there is. ```sudo ufw status``` on both machines return ```inactive```. Also, checking ```iptables -L``` there doesn't seem to be anything blocking forwarding.